# Finding Text with array and replace with link around text with a class equal to text

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, arrays, replace

So using jQuery, I'm trying to use an array to search through paragraph elements using an array and when it finds certain words it converts that word to a link with that class.

I'm trying to use this:

```
jQuery('.story').html(function(i,html) {
    var w = ['ocean','waves','bed', 'swimming'];
    $.each(w,function(i,w) {
        html = html.replace(new RegExp('<a href="" class="' + w + '">' + w + '</a>', 'g'),w[i]);
    });
    return html;
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hakarune/8XWf3/11/)

The end result would turn `ocean` into `<a href="" class="ocean">ocean</a>` et al.

But it doesn't seem to be working. I don't really understand why either. Thanks ahead of time.

m(_ _)m

_|7O

(The end plan is to have it so that those words play certain SFX when pressed and I'm basing off the class so when the word shows up again in the story it plays the same sound).

Comment: You're searching for the link, not for the bare word. And what is `r[i]`? There's no array named `r`.

Comment: `.val()` is for the value of an input element. You need to use `.html()` to change the HTML content of an element.

Comment: the r is a typo, sorry. fixed

Comment: Inside the `$.each`, `w` is the current element, not the array, so `w[i]` won't work. Don't reuse variables like that.

Comment: fixed the html part. And sorry, I'm still learning jquery.

Comment: would it be `$.each('.story',function(i,w) {` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
var w = ['ocean','waves','bed', 'swimming'],
     reg = new RegExp('(' + w.join('|') + ')','g');

jQuery('.story').html(function(_, curHtml) {
     return curHtml.replace(reg,"<a href='#' class='$1'>$1</a>");
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G76vf/)**

You need to use `html` instead of `val` and construct the regexp based on all the words so that they can be matched at once and replace the matched value with the string and using the match token, $1

Comment: YES! Thank you! and I didn't know what `$1` was, I've seen it in example code, but never explained in the book I'm reading. Thanks again dude!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. You use the same variable `i` and `w` twice. They override each other. Although that does not make a difference here
2. You use `.val` instead of `.html`. `.val` should only be used for form fields.
3. You swapped the reg exp and the replacement in the replace call

Try this:

```
jQuery('.story').html(function(i,val) {
    var w = ['ocean','waves','bed', 'swimming'];
    $.each(w, function(j,w) {
        val = val.replace(new RegExp(w, 'g'), '<a href="" class="' + w + '">' + w + '</a>');
    });
    return val;
});
```

As an extra remark: doing it the way you set this up can get you into trouble if one of the words in the array is a substring of one of the other. Watch out for this.

Answer (score 1):

How about?

```
var arr = ['ocean','waves','bed', 'swimming'];
var result = $('.story').text();
$.each(arr, function (i, val) {
    result =
      result.replace(val, '<a href="" class="' + val + '">' + val + '</a>');
});
$('.story').html(result);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8XWf3/21/

Answer (score 0):

```
    var w = ['ocean','waves','bed', 'swimming'];
    $.each(w,function(i,w) {
        jQuery('.story').html(function(i,val) {
            val = val.replace(w,'<a href="" class="' + w + '">' + w + '<\/a>');
            return val;
         });  
    });
```

**JS FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/8XWf3/22/